# copying files on windows with enumeration file extention

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer

On Windows 7 I used a default copy handler called **TeraCopy** in order to copy and manage files. mostly because of two reasons:

- The program could test files after copying
- If I selected a file in a folder, Ctr+C and Ctr+V in order to create a duplicate in the same folder, the copy got the name extension "_2" and after this "_3" and so on. So TeraCopy was enumerating the copies.

Now I have Windows 10 and the default Windows copy handler is making the "- copy" extension on the first duplicate, the "- copy - copy" on the second duplicate and so on.
And when I install TeraCopy, it is not the default copy handler in all situations. Sometimes the default Windows 10 copy handler strikes in.

Can I change the way the windows default copy handler is naming duplicates of files? So that it will enumerate them. ?

Comment: There is a registry setting where you can remove the "- Copy" part. But it would still add test_ (2), test_ (3) and so on, and the brackets can't be removed.

Comment: damn ... but then the main question should be, how I can run TeraCopy properly on Win10. Why is the default copy handler used sometimes? mostly when I work on a samba shared folder. TeraCopy only seems to work properly on the internal C drive ....

Answer (score 0):

You can make the duplicates, and then select all of them, and rename one. then it goes like this:

```
New name (1)
New name (2)
New name (3)
New name (4)
New name (5)
```

Comment: that is definitely possible, but not my intention. I do not want to rename files after I duplicated them. that takes a lot of time in total.